# How to list and filter authority records in IBM MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq, pcf

I am using MQ PCF to list authority records associated with a queue manager. Here is code.

```
    PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
    agent.setCheckResponses(false);
    PCFMessage[] responses;
    PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_INQUIRE_AUTH_RECS);
    request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_AUTH_OPTIONS,
            MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_ALL_MATCHING + MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_ENTITY_EXPLICIT + MQConstants.MQAUTHOPT_NAME_AS_WILDCARD);

    request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCACF_AUTH_PROFILE_NAME, "*");
    request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIACF_OBJECT_TYPE, MQConstants.MQOT_ALL);
    responses = agent.send(request);
```

This returns a huge number of authority records, most of these are standard/system records that MQ creates by default.

How do I change the above code (filter out default records) so that only the application specific authority records are returned?

Answer (score 1):

```
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCACF_AUTH_PROFILE_NAME, "*");
```

You used a wildcard, so the queue manager will give you everything.  Use "ABC*" to get ABC* only related authority records.

Comment: I guess I should be asking how do I get only the non standard authority records, e.i. The ones not created by mq by default.